# youtube-ios-player-helper message: "This video is restricted. Try signing in with a Google Apps account."

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I want to play embedded youtube videos in an iOS app, using the YTPlayerView provided at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Testing my code with the following video for example, https://youtu.be/jBm7O1XCYiE, I end up with the following:
** on XCode simulator: Youtube video plays as expected
** on real device (iPad mini): I receive the message "This video is restricted. Try to sign in with a Google Apps account."

Any suggestions what I should do to overcome this message on the real device?

The weirdest thing is, very rarely, YouTube lets me watch the video on the real device as well, the same video which I normally keep receiving the above error message (eventhough I do not change any codes or settings meanwhile)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this is a domestic problem..

Solution is: configuring the network settings to use a different DNS, such as Google Public DNS.

Rootcause was: In Turkey, there is access restriction to some specific web sites, and YouTube is one of them. YouTube is not completely blocked, however it just does not function normal with default DNS settings. And I have just forgotten to change the DNS of my test device.

Thanks to the government, for all the things I've learned during the last couple of days while trying to address this issue!

My next problem is now to find out how I can overcome this situation without asking the users to modify their DNS settings. Is making a VPN connection on the background the only way out??

Any answers/hints are appreciated.